# Check outside click in WinApi

Tags: winapi, events

I'm writing application in raw WinApi using C++. I'm writing my own controls from begining. I need to get information when mouse button is click outside specific HWND. Is there any build in mechanism in WinApi to do such things or maybe I need to write my own logic?

Comment: This is, in general, not possible. You could capture mouse input but this will not work when the user clicks another window, bringing it to the foreground. It sounds like a strange requirement, too. Maybe you should explain what you are really trying to solve.

Comment: Well, I write my own combobox. When I click on it, it slide down and whe I click anywhere else, it slide up

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It would essentially mean that - as long as your combobox has input focus - the user cannot click on buttons, navigate menus, etc. The user cannot even move focus to another control using the mouse.

Comment: You understand me wrong. I want to my combo work just like normal windows ComboBox but with some additional logic. For now it works just fine but I have problem with this click outside control on another HWND.

Comment: If you capture the mouse input with `SetCapture()` you'll get a `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` message when the user clicks outside your application.

Comment: But what if he click on another control in my application?

Comment: So you are really only interested in the control losing focus. [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282.aspx) is the message you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #define IDM_FILE_NEW 21
    #define IDM_FILE_OPEN 44
    #define IDM_FILE_QUIT 88

    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
   {
    HNENU hMenu;
    POINT point;

     point.x = LOWORD(lParam);
      point.y = HIWORD(lParam);

      hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
      ClientToScreen(hwnd, &point);

      AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_NEW, 
      L"&New");
      AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, 
     L"&Open");
      AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
      AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, 
       L"&Quit");

      TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, 
        point.x, point.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
      DestroyMenu(hMenu);
     }
      break;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Comment: Also, it's better if you format your code with a correct indentation: this way, other developers can understand better what you're trying to say.